# Android Swipe View with tabs, fragments and ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, tabs, swipe

I am facing problem with my android app and I cannot find working solution for this particular problem - I am starting to believe that it is not possible to achive what I try to do.

I want to have an app with tabs (DONE!). I want to swipe through those tabs with finger gesture (partialy done) and I want to display different items on those tabs as a ListView (partialy done). The problem is that when I populate ListView with my db data I cannot swipe through tabs any longer. It is like that because I change the content view to one of my fragments.

How can I keep swiping through tabs and populate list view? The other thing is that I want to call different select statement on each of my tabs dynamically - so user can mark something as his favourite and when he'll navigate to "favourites" tab he will find proper content.

Here is my code (I think this are the most important bits):
MainActivity.java

```
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     // Initilization
     viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
     actionBar = getActionBar();
     TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

     viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
     actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
     actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

     // Adding Tabs
     for (String tab_name : tabs) {
         actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                 .setTabListener(this));
     }

     /**
      * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
      * */
     viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener()  {

         @Override
         public void onPageSelected(int position) {
             // on changing the page
             // make respected tab selected
             actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
         }

         @Override
         public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
         }

         @Override
         public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
         }
     });

     setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
     myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewFromDB);
     registerForContextMenu(myList);
     openDB();
     myDb.populateDataBaseOnStart();
     populateListViewFromDB();
     registerClickCallback();

 }
 @Override
 public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
 }

 @Override
 public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
     // on tab selected
     // show respected fragment view
     viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
 }

 @Override
 public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
 }
```

Here is my ClassFragment.java:

```
public class FilmyFragment extends Fragment {

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_filmy, container, false);

    return rootView;
}
```

}

And Here is layout xml for main activity and fragment class:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" />
```

Fragment:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView android:id="@+id/listViewFromDB"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

Comment: why are you calling `setContentView()` twice ? first for `activity_main` and then `fragment_main` ?

Comment: This is part of my question - I am calling setContentView() on fragment_main as this fragment is same as fragment I provided example for. It contains ListView which I populate with data from DB. If I will not call setContentView() for that fragment ActivityMain.java will not find ListView. But I want to handle population of ListView for particular fragment. The best would be if I could do it on the list java class.

Comment: I'm sorry but you're not making sense. `setContentView()` is almost never called more than once in an `Activity`. Please try to be more clear about what you are trying to do and why, else it will be difficult to assist you.

Comment: Sorry if I am not clear. Maybe the real question should be how to display ListView on a fragment? I want to have few fragments with different ListView on each of them. I want to also have tabs. Each fragment for each tab and I want to be able to swipe between them.

Comment: why not put the listviews inside the fragments then ?

Comment: Whenever I put ListView into any of my fragments I get an error message `Cannot resole method findViewById(int)`. At first I thought I must use `setContentView` in my fragment class but I get the same error for this method

Comment: Ok. Got it. Thanks for your questions. They showed me the correct path!

Comment: "Cannot resolve method" is just a compile error, could not be fixed by calling another method like setContentView.